# Casting Constructor in Python

Tags: python, casting, copy-constructor, move-constructor

I'm using stricly typed Python, and would like to achieve something similar to the copy/move constructor overloading of C++. That is, I'd like to make my object convertible to another type using an explicit definition.

Here's an example:

```
class CallerSurface(StringEnum):
  IOS_APPLICATION = "ios_application"
  ANDROID_APPLICATION = "android_application"
  WEB_APPLICATION = "web_application"
```

which I can use with some function such as:

```
  def getResponse(data: Data, caller_name: CallerSurface) -> str:
```

I'd like to add some part of the definition of class CallerSurface to make it possible for a function that takes a param of type CallerSurface, to also take a param of type str, and just "know" how to convert the str to CallerSurface without the programmer needing to explicitly figure out a conversion.

So I want to use in the following way:

```
  caller_name: str = HTTPUtils.extractCallerFromUserAgent(request)
  response = getResponse(other_data, caller_name)
```

caller_name is a str, but getResponse takes a CallerSurface. I'd like to make the conversion be implicitly defined in then CallerSurface class.

In C++ you could achieve this by defining a copy and a move constructor that takes in string. Is there something in Python for this?

Comment: What do you mean by strictly typed Python? Python uses duck typing and does not enforce the optional type annotations in your code example.

Comment: You should already be able to do (e.g.) `CallerSurface("ios_application")`.  You can also call the `CallerSurface` constructor with another `CallerSurface` instance, which gives you a way to convert a `Union[CallerSurface, str]` to a `CallerSurface` fairly trivially.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to automate the conversion (there's no such thing as implicit type conversion of the sort you're looking for), so your options are:

1. Expand the allowed argument types (`caller_name: CallerSurface` becomes `caller_name: Union[CallerSurface, str]`), manually convert the related types to the intended type, or
2. [Use `@functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) to make multiple versions of the function, one that accepts each type, where all but one implementation just converts to the intended type and calls itself

In short, this isn't C++, and implicit type conversions aren't a thing in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't do type conversion implicitly.  It does provide things like the `__str__` magic method, but that conversion still requires an explicit call to the `str()` function.

What you want to do, I think, is leave the typing as `CallerSurface`, and use a static type checker to force the caller to do (e.g.):

```
  caller_name = HTTPUtils.extractCallerFromUserAgent(request)
  response = getResponse(other_data, CallerSurface(caller_name))
```

Using a type checker (e.g. `mypy`) is key, since that makes it impossible to forget the `CallerSurface` call (or whatever other kind of conversion needs to happen).